# Can I make my code execute a script once when I have loaded a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am making a web application in Vuejs and I am using the vue-router with single file components.

When the user enters a route, the `created()`-function on the component will be called. In the `created()`-function, I am loading data from another site, but I want this code to be executed only once, so it doesn't load every time I visit the page. Any ideas to an approach?

This is my code now:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Arrangementer</h1>
        <br>
        <div class="events">
            <Event v-for="event in events" 
                :key="event.id"
                :title="event.title"
                :desc="event.desc"
                :position="event.position"
                :start_date="event.start_date"
                :end_date="event.end_date"
                :registration="event.registration"
                :img_url="event.img_url"
                :body="event.body" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>

import Event from '../components/Event';
import axios from 'axios';
import rollbar from '../../server/logging';

export default {
    components: {
        Event
    },
    data: () => {
        return {
            events: {}
        }
    },
    created() {
        const vm = this;
        axios.get('/api/events').then((response) => {
            vm.events = response.data;
        }).catch((e) => {
            rollbar.error(e);
            vm.$notify({
                group: "varsel",
                title: "En feil oppsto",
                text: "Jeg klarte ikke å hente info :("
            });
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. You may try to save the API response in your `sessionStorage`, so it will persist until you will close your browser window.

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Arrangementer</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="events">
      <Event
        v-for="event in events"
        :key="event.id"
        :title="event.title"
        :desc="event.desc"
        :position="event.position"
        :start_date="event.start_date"
        :end_date="event.end_date"
        :registration="event.registration"
        :img_url="event.img_url"
        :body="event.body"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import Event from "../components/Event";
import axios from "axios";
import rollbar from "../../server/logging";

export default {
  components: {
    Event
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      events: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getApi() {
      try {
        const events = await axios.get("/api/events");
        sessionStorage.setItem("api_events", events);
        return events;
      } catch (err) {
        rollbar.error(e);
        this.$notify({
          group: "varsel",
          title: "En feil oppsto",
          text: "Jeg klarte ikke å hente info :("
        });
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    const events = sessionStorage.getItem("api_events");
    if (events) {
      this.events = events;
    } else {
      this.getApi();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked better that what I thought about! :D

Comment: Great! Happy to hear that! 

Answer (score 0):

You can load data at the parent component and then pass it to your component. I don't know how you initiate your component, but you can first load the data and than initiate the child component with passing loaded data. You can also create a middleware component between your parent and child component just to keep the data permanently. You can create it on creating parent or using lazy load. Another solution - really not recommended - would be to not remove your component, but just hide it, which is really bad for the performance of your application. You need also keep in mind that all these solutions will cause keeping the loaded data in the memory all the time, so it's not memory efficient (unless you add some kind of garbage collector to remove this data from the memory, for example after n time).